# Controlling the browser from command line

Tags: bash, firefox, google-chrome

I recently switched most of my work from Mac (back) to Linux - with no regrets.

The one thing I still need to figure out is how to control a browser via scripts from the command line.

Primary purpose is to control the *currently running* browser to fill in forms that I use repeatedly (i.e.: bank payments).

This is something that I used to do via AppleScript+JavaScript on Chrome and before that via perl+MozRepl on Firefox.

Key requirement

- the ability to read stdin - directly or not (via bash/perl scripting is ok)
- the ability to fill in forms (NOT via URL)
- NOT headless (this is for bank payments)

AppleScript is not available on Linux (duh!) and MozRepl has been deprecated a couple years ago.

Any (lightweight) solutions?

Comment: Does it control the _currently running_ Firefox? I'm looking into it but it seems to start another browser session

Comment: @user535733 - done